# sharepoint and sql server 2008 audit

Tags: sharepoint, sql-server-2008

I have activated the audit feature on wss_content database and alldocstream table but in the audit log does not show anything if the users access the file in the doc lib of sharepoint. However I tried to capture the sql statements while accessing the file in the doc lib and found that one of the stored proc is "proc_FetchDocForHttpGet". I executed this "proc_FetchDocForHttpGet" proc manually and managed to be captured in the audit log.

Does anyone know why none of activities in sharepoint is being captured by sql audit?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't **item-level auditing** what you're looking for? It's a feature of SharePoint, not SQL Server.

- [Item-Level Auditing with SharePoint Server 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397403%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [Document and list item auditing with SharePoint 2010](http://www.sharemuch.com/2011/03/17/document-and-list-item-auditing-with-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: that wasn't what I'm after.. However amazingly that is the next topic I need to look at.. Anyway.. i found the issue why all my web application was not getting audited by SQL server. Simply bacause I need to filter to public server role principal on the audit specification.